# Left Div and Right Div should be Equal in Height..!

Tags: html, css

Two requirement i have.

1. Left div have to be the same height as right div
2. I need a footer div.

and this is the code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="base">
    <div id="leftleft">left
        <br/>I WANT THIS HEIGHT TO BE SAME AS RIGHT DIV
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="rightright">RIGHT DIV HEIGHT WILL BE
        <br/>CHANGED DYNAMICALLY.
        <br/>I WANT TO MATCH THE LEFT
        <br/>AND RIGHT DIV HEIGHT EQUALLY.
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>right
        <br/>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        this has to be in the bottom
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#leftleft {
    background: #1B8BC6;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
}
#rightright {
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
}
#footer{
    clear:both;
}
#base {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
}
```

**Fiddle**,

[Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/6/)

If I put `float:left` the footer goes down, but the left div height doesn't match.

if i delete `float:left` the footer div doesn't go down :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

**Remove** `float:left;`

As like this code

```
#base {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}
#leftleft {
    background: #1B8BC6;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
   vertical-align:top;
}
#rightright {
    display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#footer{
    display:table-row;
    width:100%;background:red;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/9Kwry/7/)**

Comment: thank you. this is almost to the goal, but i want the footer div to be in the middle of the whole width.

Answer (score 0):

use `<table>`

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Left Div
</td>
<td>Right Div
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<footer>Footer</footer>
```

Comment: Don’t use tables to lay-out, if you don’t wanna be 90s-late. Use **CSS flex-box** instead:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

how about using min-height in CSS of each DIV

`min-height: 300px`

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HrWNp/2/)

OR

use table. In table, td tags are always in same width and height.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [approach](http://jsfiddle.net/9Kwry/9/).

Add height:100% to body and html(for ensure all div inside body can inherit the height).

```
body,html{height:100%;}
```

Good Luck!!